# Permutating all possible combinations while staying sorted?

Tags: algorithm, go, iteration, permutation

I have structs that contain integer values `x` and `y`.

I have two equal struct lists, `A[]` and `B[]`, and my constraint is that they must stay ordered by `x`.

My challenge is that I need to determine, for any index, if the `y` value for list `B[]` is greater than the `y` value for list `A[]`.

The confusing thing is that you can swap the positions of the structs **as long as `x` is in order**.

It's a difficult thing to explain, so I'll give an example.

| `A[]` | `B[]` | Index | Comparison | Pass/Fail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `struct{x = 1, y = 1}` | `struct{x = 1, y = 2}` | 0 | 1 < 2 | pass |
| `struct{x = 2, y = 1}` | `struct{x = 2, y = 2}` | 1 | 1 < 2 | pass |
| `struct{x = 3, y = 1}` | `struct{x = 3, y = 2}` | 2 | 1 < 2 | pass |

The table above works, because when the `x` values are in order, the `y` values in `A[]` are less than the `y` values in `B[]`.

But for the example

| `A[]` | `B[]` | Index | Comparison | Pass/Fail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `struct{x = 1, y = 1}` | `struct{x = 1, y = 2}` | 0 | 1 < 2 | pass |
| `struct{x = 2, y = 3}` | `struct{x = 2, y = 7}` | 1 | 3 < 7 | pass |
| `struct{x = 3, y = 6}` | `struct{x = 2, y = 4}` | 2 | *6 > 4* | fail |

Index `1` and `2` from `B[]` can be swapped, while still being in order with respect to `x`. If we swap the order to:

| `A[]` | `B[]` | Index | Comparison | Pass/Fail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `struct{x = 1, y = 1}` | `struct{x = 1, y = 2}` | 0 | 1 < 2 | pass |
| `struct{x = 2, y = 3}` | `struct{x = 2, y = 4}` | 1 | 3 < 4 | pass |
| `struct{x = 3, y = 6}` | `struct{x = 2, y = 7}` | 2 | 6 < 7 | pass |

the `y` values in `A[]` will be less than the `y` values in same index in `B[]`.

Is there any specific algorithm I should be searching for? Should I permutate through all possible combinations, and then check if it matches my requirements, or is there a way to permutate specific values while staying in-order?

Comment: Why after the swap did the `x` values in `A[]` wind up out of order?

Comment: @btilly Fixed. It was a typo.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. So many SO questions are poorly done. This is good. And it's a pretty interesting problem.

Comment: It looks like the 'comparison' column in the first table has its '<' signs flipped. Also, can you confirm that the y-values in B must be *strictly* greater than the corresponding y-values in A?

Comment: @kcsquared Fixed, and that is true.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can simply sort both `A` and `B` by `x` then `y`.  If that passes, you have your answer.  If that fails to pass, then you can prove that there is no way to reorder both lists to get a pass.

Comment: In the event of a more complicated list, where `A[]` = `1:1, 2:1, 3:1, 3;2, 3:3`, and `B[]` = `1:1, 1:2, 1:3, 2:1, 3:1`, the first 3 items in `A[]` can be swapped to index 3, and the last 3 items in `B[]` can be swapped to index 3. Sorting one, then the other doesn't necessarily work because there can be duplicates.

Edit: To save space, I'm replacing the struct with the form of ``x:y``.